# how to fix "Operation not permitted" when i use launchctl in macos catalina

Tags: python, macos, sh

I'm setting up a launchctl server to run a python file regularly. So I write a.plist file , auto.sh file and it works well. 
However, after I installed Macos Catalina, it failed. 
I write "ls -l" in auto.sh to check file permission, 
log shows that:

```
ls: .: Operation not permitted
python3: can't open file 'auto.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

How can I do to fix it? Thank you so much.

here is my code:

auto.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
. ~/.bash_profile
conda activate base
cd /Users/gassy/Documents/
ls -l
python3 auto.py
```

I put such .plist file in /Users/gassy/Library/LaunchAgents/com.gassy.fangzhou.plist

```
    ...
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/gassy/auto/launch.sh</string>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you have is not with Python, but with the file permissions on `auto.py` or the path leading up to it. What user account is used to run the script? Does that user have the necessary permissions on both those executables and the parent directory? Reason I suspect directory permissions is that `ls` is failing along with `auto.py`.

You might have some luck if you move everything out of `/Users/gassy/Documents` and to another location, perhaps under `/opt` or `/var` or similar, and then make sure that the permissions are sane. I know that macos treats some of those directores under `/Users/<user>` special, sometimes in a less-than-helpful way...

Comment: Just to add: I would not try fiddling with the permissions on `/Users/gassy/Documents`, I have had a not very fun time trying to modify those 'special' macos directories. Best to leave it alone and move your script somewhere that won't make macos angry...

Comment: Thanks for your help~ I try to move `auto.sh` to `\opt` and run it in launchctl by `launchctl start com.gassy.fangzhou`. However, it raise the same error as before

Comment: @Lucas Did you also edit `auto.sh` to `cd /opt` instead of `cd /Users/gassy/Documents` ?

Comment: I puted `auto.py` in another folder in `/Users/gassy/Documents`  ,now I move it to `/opt` ,It works!  I check the root, and find the permissions of `/Users/gassy/Documents` is `drwx------@`. It's like that Macos Catalina changes the permissions of `/Users/<user>/Documents` .  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 39):

Finally figure it out...

It's a problem related to Catalina new permission system, the `/bin/bash` need to have the [full disk access].

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This also helped, how to get bash into that list quickly: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376474/enabling-bin-bash-on-catalina-invisible-to-system-preferences-security-p

Comment: This was my issue, but I had also forgotten the shebang in my .sh script, so by default it runs inside "sh" not "bash"
So remember your shebang like this: #!/bin/bash

Comment: I can't find this setting in recent macOS versions....

Answer (score 5):

In the spirit of the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege):

If you don't want to give `bash` Full Disk Access you can create a [binary wrapper](https://github.com/restic/restic/issues/2051#issuecomment-560271504).

Create a C source code file `launch.c`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  int status = system("/path/to/launch.sh");
  int ret = WEXITSTATUS(status);
  return ret;
}
```

Then compile it to `launch`.

```
gcc -Wall -o launch launch.c
```

Grant it [Full Disk Access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384314/10074) add it to the launchd Property List File.

Comment: Also, the first time you run it through the launchctl server (e.g. `launchctl start com.test.app`), you should automatically get a System Preferences notification that "launch wants to access your Documents folder. Allow?"  which saves you the trouble of navigating to System Preferences and limits the disc access to only the folder you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions of the file by using the `chmod` command in your bash script, before running `python3 auto.py`.

`chmox +x auto.py` should do, however I would recommend you to read more about it and be specific on your use case.

Comment: This is what i suggested at first, but I think the problem is a bit larger than just `auto.py`.  Notice that the `ls` command is failing on that directory too.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of @mingxin's solution worked for me: Basically the same steps but instead of giving full disk access to `bash` in Security & Privacy, give full access to `python3` (which on my Big Sur macOS system is in `/usr/bin`).

Answer (score 0):

Giving "Full Disk Access" to your shell (/bin/sh or /bin/bash) would work but it's a manual process you cannot script/automate (something fundamental when crafting a CI system for example). I think people all over the internet got side-tracked by this.

A better solution is to move the files that need to be accessed/run by your daemons/agents to a location that is not ~/Documents, ~/Desktop etc. ~/bin for instance, works just fine.